# ssh-agent needs to start each time on my server

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent

I have used this bitbucket tutorial for providing ssh access to the git repo:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678

But now each time I want to use the git it says I have no permissions until I do:

```
ssh-agent /bin/bash
&&
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

why is this happening? I did it easily on my local machine, but the remote server is not working good.

update

when I do

```
ssh-agent
```

I get this

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-blGr6z5dJjit/agent.14183; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=14184; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 14184;
```

but than I try to do git fetch, I get this:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

even after I add the key

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

I get this error

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question was a bit unclear, so this answer may really for a different question. But since the answer may still prove useful to others, I think it is worthwhile keeping around.

When you type `ssh-agent /bin/bash` an instance of ssh-agent is started, which will keep running for as long as that shell is active. By default that ssh-agent will be used only by that shell, and it will terminate once you close that shell.

If instead you only type `ssh-agent`, an agent will be started in the background, which keeps running, even if you close the shell. The ssh-agent command will print commands on stdout, which can be typed in to start using that ssh-agent. You would have to type those commands each time.

You can start a background ssh-agent and start using it in the current shell by typing `eval $(ssh-agent)`. However you would have to store the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable somewhere and set it if you log in again.

With that background information in place, I have three suggestions as to how to go about always having the agent available.

- Use a screen session on the server. When you start the screen type `eval $(ssh-agent) ; screen`, that agent will stay running on the server, and if you connect to that screen again later, it will still remember which agent to use.
- Insert commands in your `~/.bash_profile` file to find the active agent, if one exists and set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.
- Use ssh agent forwarding to use the agent on the client rather than one on the server. Make sure you understand the security implications of that, before you use it.

Finding the ssh-agent from `~/.bash_profile` could be done with a script looking like this

```
#!/bin/bash

for P in /tmp/ssh-*/agent.*
do
    if [ -O "$P" ] && [ -O "$(dirname "$P")" ]
    then
        L=$(SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$P" timeout 1s ssh-add -l > >(wc -l))
        case $? in
            0)
                echo "$L $P"
                ;;
            1)
                echo "0 $P"
                ;;
        esac
    fi &
done | sort -rn | if read N P
then
    echo "SSH_AUTH_SOCK='$P'; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
else
    ssh-agent
fi
```

Which could be invoked from `~/.bash_profile` like this `eval $(find-agent)` (assuming the script was named find-agent.)

Comment: thanks for your help, but when I did -->me# ssh-agent it said it open the agent but when I do -->me# ssh-add ~/.ssh/pr_key it says: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: can you write the commandes you suggest to do line by line... Im a newbie so it will help me a lot

Comment: Typing only `ssh-agent` will start an agent and print out the commands you need to type in, before you can communicate with it. Those commands you can type again in another shell. If you type `eval $(ssh-agent)` it will automatically run the needed commands instead of printing them on the screen. I forgot the eval part the first time around.

Comment: why exactly do I need that ssh-agent? my ssh key has no password... I want to perform a simple ssh connection

Comment: Then it is not clear to me, what you say is working and what you say is not working. What did you do, that worked on the local machine? And what server does it not work on? And how did you see that it does not work on that server?

Comment: sorry for the mix up, I update the post with some of the details you suggested.

Comment: Your update only explained those parts, which were already clear, and which I responded to above. Typing `ssh-agent` by itself will start the agent but not use it, unless you copy and run the commands output by ssh-agent. Typing `eval $(ssh-agent)` instead, will start an agent and use it. What is still missing is the git commands you ran locally and on the server, as well as the context in which they were run, and the output, which they produced.

Answer (score 1):

An ssh command may fail with the error message `Permission denied (publickey).`, but work if you load the same key into an agent beforehand, if you have misconfigured the ssh client.

By default `ssh` and `ssh-add` will load keys from the same places, so either both will find the needed key, or neither will find it. However in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config`, you can override the path used by `ssh` through the `IdentityFile` setting.

If `~/.ssh/config` contains an incorrect `IdentityFile` setting, you will see the symptoms described in your post.